# How do I move an image anywhere on the screen with CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-float, padding, margin

```
.image-one {
  padding-left: 600px;
}

.image-two {
  padding: 10px 600px 200px 100px;
}

.image-three {
  padding-left: 600px;
}
```

I have three PNG images that I am trying to place anywhere I want on the screen.
I still don't understand how the whole system works. To move an image up and down, left and right on the screen, I need to use *padding* or *margin*, right? I tried with both and I can't figure out how to do it. It doesn't work with *float: left;* or *float: right;* either. In a nutshell, the question is: how do you go about moving ANYTHING on the screen and place it wherever you want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it's 'position' according to your needs.
if you want to move the image anywhere on the screen then I suggest to this , its just an example.

```
 .image-one{
   position:absolute;
   left:30px;
   top:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try putting them in a div container that is set to display flex, and then manipulate these images as flex items:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/